# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to instantiate a `viewModel` class which contains a init block where I'm trying to send a Get request with volley. The problem is when I'm trying to instantiate this class in my Fragment class I'm getting this error and I don't know why. Maybe the context from the constructor would be the problem? Thanks:

**ViewModel class**

```
class BooksFragmentViewModel(c : Context) : ViewModel() {

lateinit var cont: Context
var books: MutableLiveData<MutableList<BookItem>> = MutableLiveData<MutableList<BookItem>>()
var triggerAddBook = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var triggerDeleteBook = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var triggerEditBook = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var bookRepo: BookRepository = BookRepository()
var bookItemAdd: BookItem? = null
var bookItemDelete: BookItem? = null
var bookItemEdit : BookItem? = null
var bookNew: LiveData<BookItem> = Transformations.switchMap(triggerAddBook) {
    if (it != null && it)
        addBook()
    else
        null
}

  init {
        books = bookRepo.booksGetRequest(c)
    }
```

**Fragment Class**

```
class BooksFragment : Fragment(), BooksAdapter.OnDeleteBtnClicked, BooksAdapter.OnEditBtnClicked {
lateinit var booksModel: BooksFragmentViewModel
var position: Int = 0

private var adapter: BooksAdapter = BooksAdapter(this, this)
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    booksModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(BooksFragmentViewModel::class.java)
    booksLoading_progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    var c: Context? = context
    if (c != null) {
        booksModel.setContext(c)
    }
```

Comment: are you forget to add Viewmodel factory?

Comment: how should I do that? thanks @MohamedAbdelraZek

Comment: okay, I will post answer to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is indeed because of the primary constructor with arguments. You are asking the `ViewModelProvider` to create an instance of `BooksFragmentViewModel` class but the provider does not know anything about the expected argument.

*[Here is a post](https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f) on that topic.*

#### How to fix the issue?

1. Get rid of all primary constructor arguments if possible. That should be the easiest way;
2. Create `ViewModelProvider.Factory` that will handle creation of your view model.

The first option is clear, but for the second one, you should do the following.

Create `ViewModelProvider.Factory`:

```
class BooksFragmentViewModelFactory (val context: Context) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(BooksFragmentViewModel::class.java)) {
            return BooksFragmentViewModel(context) as T
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to create instance of the ${modelClass.simpleName}")
        }
    }
}
```

Use the factory with `ViewModelProvider`:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val bookViewModelFactory = BooksFragmentViewModelFactory(requireContext())
        booksModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), bookViewModelFactory).get(BooksFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        booksLoading_progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

For more explanation check out this [codelab from Google (step 8)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/#7). There is enough examples to understand the basics of how to use a view model factory.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is the solution which solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a `ViewModel` with arguments (like context in your example), then you need to use a `Factory` to pass any argument to that `ViewModel`

```
 booksModel = ViewModelProvider(this,object :
        ViewModelProvider.Factory{
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return booksModel(requireActivity()) as T
        }
    }).get(booksModel::class.java)
```

Comment: `activity?.application!!` can be replaced with `activity!` or even better - `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()`.

Comment: you can pass any context related to what you are going to do inside ViewModel

Comment: I just pointed out more concise and clear way to get the context.

Comment: Btw, your code looks like something is missing and I can tell for sure that `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated.